# magento getting product type from product sku

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How can i get the product type(simplee,configurable/grouped ...) using product sku or id, i have loaded product collection and from that trying to prict type by

```
$_product->getTypeId()
```

But its not printing the product type. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `$_product->getTypeId()` should work. If it doesn't then try `$_product->getResource()->getTypeId()`

Comment: Hi chapagain, sorry this process is under order reporting module and i guess thats the reason why i didnt get type_id.

Comment: And when i used "product_type" i am getting the result. Thanks Chapagain.

Comment: from your blog i used $collectionconfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')       ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable')); but here i want all the sku's of its inner products. Please help me

Comment: @Ela, that is a completely different question. Maybe you should post it as another question so that it can be answered directly.

Comment: @Ela: You have product collection in order reporting module. So, I think you also have product ID over there. Then, you can load the product from product ID. After that, I think you should be able to get the product type.

Answer (score 8):

I got product type following way in phtml file

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$productType=$product->getTypeID();
//Simple Product    
if($productType == 'simple')
{   
  echo "Simple Product";
}                           
//Configurable Product
if($productType == 'configurable')
{   
  echo "Configurable Product";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you know that you can see whats inside an object by just performing print_r($_product->getData())

Comment: Hi Anton, yes i know how to debug in magento. print_r,var_dump,Zend_Debug::dump but am in order reporting module so thats the reason i didnt get the type_id.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tip.

If you are iterating though Cart Items, then use the getProductType() for the product type information. For example -

```
foreach( $cartItems as $item ){
    if($item->getProductType() == "configurable") {
```