# Static Block for specific products in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there any way to do this :

I have two kinds of products, Handmade and ready women accessories. for handmade products I want a block under the price that tell the customer "This Product is 100% Handmade" and for the ready product nothing. So it will be only for the Handmade.

I already have a block but it is visible to all products, so I want it to be visible only for Handmade products.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: are handmade and ready women accessories categories?

Comment: no, please check here http://www.glittercorner.com/women/000237.html

Comment: You can get the "product type" on a product page and then, check if it equals to the product type you need - like 'handmade' and if it is, display the special message. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177890/magento-getting-product-type-from-product-sku

Comment: Thank you, but i think this wont work as all the products are under Simple Type. what do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not create an attribute specifically for the Handmade products? e.g the attribute could be called 'IsHandmade'.

Then on your product page (view.phtml) under the price have something like this?:

```
<?php if ($product->getIsHandMade == 'Yes'):
  echo 'This Product is 100% Handmade';
endif; ?>
```

Comment: i did that but instead of   echo 'This Product is 100% Handmade';  i make it <p class="handmade"><?php echo $block_detail_product_page_1;?></p> , as i want the text of This product is 100%..etc to be bold and red.  but now even if the attribute Handmade set to NO or Yes it show on the page, any idea ?

Comment: I did the following improvements to the code and its perfect now!: <?php if($_product->getHandmade()):?> <p class="handmade"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_detail_product_p‌​age_1')->toHtml(); ?></p> <?php endif; ?> , im sorry i dont know how to use comment codes